# Sound Design Birthday Ideas

Tags: obscure, movies, sound-design

Hello everyone,

An executive of the studio I work at has a birthday coming up and my coworkers and I want to give something with a sound twist to it.

I had the thought of giving 5 great examples of movies with fantastic sound design - but ones most likely never seen before. This rules out the box office hits within the past 10 years or so.

So, if you don't mind, would you care to share 5 obscure movies (not graphic, inappropriate or offensive) which have awesome, awesome, fantastic, wonderful examples of great sound design?

Uncle Boonmee and Boy comes to mind.

Please, Tim, I'm sure you have a bunch of these off the top of your head. (also, how can I buy a copy of Boy? I'm searching for it now with no luck).

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: My birthday is the 27th, woohoo!

Comment: Not sure about offshore but this site ships internationally
http://www.mightyape.co.nz/product/DVD/Boy/7275312/

Answer (score 2):

"The Conversation" and "THX 1138" spring to mind.

Comment: Definitely seconded.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

Touch the Sound
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0424509/
(great documentary about deaf percussionist Evelyn Glennie)

3-Iron
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0423866/
(a great movie with only six lines of dialogue)

Not sure if its out on DVD but:
The Sound of Noise
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1278449/

Is he at all musical? 
I'd be pretty impressed with one of those punch-your-own-tune music boxes:
http://www.grand-illusions.com/acatalog/Music_and_Audio_Toys.html

Another option, I gave someone their own domain name as a birthday present...

Will add any others as I think of them....

Answer (score 1):

Check out "into great Silence" -- lots of silence!  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478160/

Comment: To be honest, I never got that film. In fact it's the only film I regretted not walking out on.

Answer (score 1):

Kwaidan (1964)
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058279/

Answer (score 1):

The Hunger has some interesting stuff
Most Robert Altman films have good sound.  MASH has a really interesting approach to dialog and sound - people talking over each other, very naturalistic performances.

ALso, a really interesting doc about the guy who invented the Theremin (called "Theremin").  Not really about sound design, but in the ear ballpark.